Safe to install foil faced insulation over insulated HVAC line?
I have an exterior overhang on the side of my home with exposed/empty voids.
These voids are the spaces between floor joists in a crawl space.
I'm trying to seal off these voids to keep the drafty air from coming through to the subfloor of the room above it. I plan on encapsulating this crawlspace with a dehumidifier afterwards to deal with excess moisture.
Running underneath these voids are a few cables - I've noted 1 xhhw electrical line and 1 insulated HVAC line (didn't check the others).
In order to seal off these voids and be water-tight, I plan on using foil-faced foam board (pictured, 2nd photo), which will sit maybe 1" above these lines but may sometimes rub against them. The foil side of the foam board will face the ground.
My question is: Are there any safety issues with these HVAC/electrical lines being right underneath the foil of the insulation? (Or sometimes touching them?)
Will the foil ever cause enough heat to be a risk to them?
(Looks like the XHHW line is rated up to 90 degrees C/ 194 degrees F, so more worried about the HVAC line)


(I also plan on tying these cables together later)
